# How to create 4 separate lists of first and last names?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to Python and I just started learning.

Below is the nested list of strings as names I have.

```
qualifier_2_0 = {'KKR' : {'Chris Lynn': 4, 
                      'Sunil Narine': 10, 
                      'Gautam Gambhir (c)': 12, 
                      'Robin Uthappa (wk)': 1, 
                      'Ishank Jaggi': 28, 
                      'Colin Grandhomme': 0,
                      'Suryakumar Yadav': 31,
                      'Piyush Chawla': 2,
                      'Nathan Coulter-Nile': 6,
                      'Umesh Yadav': 2,
                      'Ankit Rajpoot': 4,},

                'MI': {'Lendl Simmons': 3,
                      'Parthiv Patel (wk)': 14,
                      'Ambati Rayudu': 6,
                      'Rohit Sharma (c)': 26,
                      'Krunal Pandya': 45,
                      'Kieron Pollard': 9,}}
```

I have to create 4 separate lists as below.

1. First names of KKR  Eg. ['Chris', 'Sunil, 'Gautam', 'Robin',.......]
2. Second names of KKR
3. First names of MI
4. Second names of MI

Please help me in solving this.

Comment: What've you tried so far?

Comment: like my homie @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ said, please also see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I tried to separate the KKR and MI as A and B. 

    A = list(qualifier_2_0['KKR'].keys())
    B = list(qualifier_2_0['MI'].keys())

Comment: I will give you hint. Try iterating over the nested dictionaries and split the keys on whitespace. Try to code this and you will run into multiple issues later e.g. leading/trailing whitespaces, more than 2 components in a name etc. Solve these problems by browsing StackOverflow again.

Comment: Start by choosing one of the four lists and describe **in words** how you would build it. If it helps, imagine how you would do it without a computer.

Comment: The first two and the second two are the same. So really you only have two problems.

Comment: @ShyamnathR, if you're still stuck, steps 1. and 2. are here, you should be able to get step 3. and step 4. almost *exactly* the same, just have to change ***one*** string, see if it makes sense: https://repl.it/@downshift/DevotedUntriedPrairiedog. Or *hey!* better yet checkout the full answer below...good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over the `KKR` and `MI` keys and extract what you want with simple list comprehensions:

```
>>> [x.split()[0] for x in qualifier_2_0['KKR']]
['Chris', 'Sunil', 'Gautam', 'Robin', 'Ishank', 'Colin', 'Suryakumar', 'Piyush', 'Nathan', 'Umesh', 'Ankit']
>>> [x.split()[1] for x in qualifier_2_0['KKR']]
['Lynn', 'Narine', 'Gambhir', 'Uthappa', 'Jaggi', 'Grandhomme', 'Yadav', 'Chawla', 'Coulter-Nile', 'Yadav', 'Rajpoot']
>>> [x.split()[0] for x in qualifier_2_0['MI']]
['Lendl', 'Parthiv', 'Ambati', 'Rohit', 'Krunal', 'Kieron']
>>> [x.split()[1] for x in qualifier_2_0['MI']]
['Simmons', 'Patel', 'Rayudu', 'Sharma', 'Pandya', 'Pollard']
```

**Note:** Their is a lot of repetition above, you can condense/simplify it as you please.